# CS1705 C# MySQL connector/NET 8.0

Tags: c#, .net, mysql-connector

So I'm trying to access a MySQL server in a UWP C# application, and whenever I try to compile I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1705  Assembly 'MySql.Data' with identity 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' uses 'System.Data.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Data.Common' with identity 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    TestApp C:\Users\super\Documents\C#\TestApp\CSC 1   Active
```

Apparently this means that `MySQL.Data.dll` is using a different version of the `System.Data.Common` assembly?? I'm not sure what I need to do to rectify this, any help would be very much appreciated! :)

This is the file where I use the DLL:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data.Types;


/// <summary>
/// The MySQLConnector namespace contains a class which will be used to provide a layer of
/// abstraction to connecting to a MySQL database. This will primarily be used for 
/// retrieving data about a user.
/// </summary>

namespace MySQLConnector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The DBConnection class is the class that will provide the aforementioned abstraction
    /// </summary>
    class DBConnection
    {
        private string connectionString;     // String that will be used to connect to the DB
        private MySqlConnection connection;  // MySQLConnection object

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor method, sets up the MySqlConnection object and the connection string
        /// based on the supplied parameters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="server">Hostname/IP address of the MySQL server</param>
        /// <param name="db">Name of the database</param>
        /// <param name="uid">Username to login with</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password to login with</param>
        public DBConnection(string server, string db, string uid, string password)
        {
            connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={db};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to open a connection to the MySql server.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>true: the connection was successful, false: the connection failed</returns>
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempt to close the connection to the MySql server
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>true: Connection was closed successfully, false: the connection closure failed.</returns>
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public User QueryUser(string username)
        {
            User result = null;
            string query = $"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username like {username}";

            if (this.OpenConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);

                MySqlDataReader reader = (MySqlDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result = new User();
                    result.id = reader["id"].ToString();
                    result.username = reader["username"].ToString();
                    result.password = reader["password"].ToString();
                }
            }

            this.CloseConnection();

            return result;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User class, represents a user that has been retrieved from the database
    /// </summary>
    class User
    {
        public string id;
        public string username;
        public string password;
    }
}
```

If you need any other information let me know :)

I've tried to use the `MySql.Data.dll` file that is present in the other directories downloaded with the connector, but they don't seem to make much of a difference. I'm currently using: `Assemblies\net6.0\MySql.Data.dll`, because I am using .NET 6.0.201.

So I switched to the `Assemblies\netstandard2.0\MySql.Data.dll` dll, and installed the netstandard 2.0 library through NuGet, and I now have different errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\XamlCompiler\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(584,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Debug\App.xbf" because it was not found.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\XamlCompiler\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(584,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Debug\MainPage.xbf" because it was not found.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\XamlCompiler\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(584,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Debug\\TestApp.xr.xml" because it was not found.
```

I checked the directory specified in the error message, and the files indeed do not exist, any ideas on what I can do here?

Comment: Does the TestApp project have a NuGet package reference to version 4.2.1.0 of System.Data.Common?

Comment: I clicked on "manage NuGet packages", and it only showed the UWP package, I searched for "System.Data.Common" on the browse tab but the highest available version was 4.3.0. System.Data.Common is in the dependencies list for the UWP package though

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue by removing manual references to `MySql.Data.dll`, updating visual studio, adding `MySql.Data.dll` through NuGet instead, and removed the System.Data.Common and netstandard 2.0 packages I had installed through NuGet earlier, this allowed it to build, and from then I just had some SQL issues to fix before it worked fine :)